# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject' to type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, windows-8.1

After installing Update 4 to Visual Studio 2012, when I try to add a controller right-clicking on the Controllers folder in the Solution Explorer and selecting "Add -> Controler" I am getting following exception:

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject' to type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'.

This is how Visual Studio is presenting the error:
[image]

This error is happening only for brand new projects, fortunately I am not getting this error in my projects that were in development.

Additional information: The MVC template that I choose was: "Basic", but I got the same problem for "Empty", "Internet Application" and "Intranet Application" templates as well.

Comment: Are you creating a controller that has pre generated action methods?

Comment: No, It is a brand new project, created from the scratch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was restart my PC and allow Windows 8.1 to install pending updates.