# Cannot reference Entity Framework, cannot create new controller

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Things are just going downhill for me it seems, ugh! I'm having a lot of difficulties learning how to use `DbContext` and for some reason decided to remove a reference to the Entity Framework - or something of the sort from the solution. As a result `DbContext` is no longer recognized and I haven't been able to add the Entity Framework reference back, or whatever it was that I removed under references. I thought that adding `System.Data.Entity` back would be enough.

The Entity Framework is still installed and doesn't let me reinstall on the Package Manager Console... so I decided to start over since I haven't gotten far anyway. The new MVC4 project simply does not allow me to even add a controller. Instead I get an error message saying:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject' to type
>   'System.Collections.Enumerable'.

I have zero idea of what is going on.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20029199/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-management-automation-pscustomobject-to-t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added back Entity Framework manually from within the project folder. I don't know why this would even effect future empty projects.

```
packages\EntityFramework.6.1.1\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

PSCustomObject sounds like a PowerShell issue. Maybe try a Visual Studio repair install.

Comment: Gave it a shot. No improvement. :/